# How to use uploaded images inside JSP pages (Spring MVC)

Tags: spring, image, jsp, upload

I'm implementing a web application using Spring MVC. I'm trying to implement the module that allows to upload images. I'm using Apache Commons FileUpload and this is the controller that handle the post request:

```
/**
 * Upload single file using Spring Controller
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                         @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        String fileContentType = file.getContentType();
        if (contentTypes.contains(fileContentType)) {
            // You have the correct extension
            // rest of your code here
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                // Creating the directory to store file
                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "bills");
                if (!dir.exists())
                    dir.mkdirs();


                // Create the file on server
                File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                        + File.separator + name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                System.out.println("Server File Location="
                        + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

                return "redirect:/";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //TODO handle error
            }
        } else {
            //TODO handle error
        }
    } else {
        //TODO handle error
    }
}
```

My first doubt is where should i save the images uploaded? Right now the directory is inside a GlassFish folder, is it ok? And I don't know why but the uploaded picture has no extension... is a simple file without any extension!

Now I want to let the user access these images but I don't know how to insert those inside the JSP page. I know that I should save the path inside the database relating it to a specified user but I don't know what to do next. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

About the way how to use uploaded images, I found this solution that seems working but I don't know if it's the best one or not. Inside the jsp file I have this:

```
<spring:url value="/file/download/" var="url"/>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="${url}${imageName}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Where *imageName* is a value inside the model that contains, as the name clearly says, the name of the file, and *url* contains the path of the service that returns the stream of the image. This HTTP request is handled by the following controller:

```
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImageWithMediaType(@PathVariable("name") String name) throws IOException {
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home")
        String partialPath = File.separator + "bills" + File.separator + name + ".png"    
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(rootPath + partialPath);
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(file);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    }
```

Do you think this is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use [Spring Content](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content)?  Then you don't need to implement any of that controller code at all.  Assuming you are using Spring Boot (let me know if you are not) then it would look something like this:

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-fs-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

> SpringBootApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourSpringBootApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(YourSpringBootApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Configuration
  @EnableFilesystemStores
  public static class StoreConfig {
    File filesystemRoot() {
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
        File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "bills");
        if (!dir.exists())
          dir.mkdirs();
    }

    // this bean is the spring resource loader that will be used by
    // the product store  
    @Bean
    public FileSystemResourceLoader fsResourceLoader() throws Exception 
    {
      return new FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }
  }

  @StoreRestResource(path="upload")
  public interface BillStore extends Store<String> {
    //
  }
}
```

Note that you are not writing any controller code here but this is enough to create a REST-based content service at `/upload` that actually supports full CRUD functionality (as well as  video streaming in case that us useful to you).  Create == POST, Read == GET (include byte-range support), Update == PUT, Delete == DELETE.

e.g.

`POST /upload/my-image.jpg`

will store the uploaded image to `System.getProperty("catalina.home") + File.Separator + "bills" + "my-image/jpg"`.

I am assuming you want your users to eventually be able to view their images after upload, upload new versions and possibly delete as well.  Given this `/upload` is probably not a great name.  But it is what you used in the question so what I went with in my answer.  IF you really do just want upload functionality then you can use Spring Security to make the other actions impossibly to perform.